# Searching on JSON pages

Tags: php, json

I am searching products on an e-commerce website using their API. The API returns all the information in JSON format as a response. Each JSON response has 50 items and a URL that has 50 other items and so on. So to match the searched string with product titles, I need to parse all the JSON files sequentially. But if the item to be searched is on the last page, it is taking about 40 minutes to reach there. Can you please help on how I can reduce that time?

My website is currently hosted on localhost(XAMPP).

index.php

```
$fk = new Flipkart();

$fk->getProductFeedJason($fk->result);

for($i=0; $i<51; $i++)
{
  if($fk->flag==1)
    break;
  $fk->curl($fk->links[$i]);
  $fk->getProducts($fk->result, $sstring);
}
```

flipkart.php

```
<?php

class Flipkart
{

    private $baseUrl = "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/psblesson.json";

    private $headers = array(
            'Fk-Affiliate-Id: id',
            'Fk-Affiliate-Token: token'
            );

    public $result;
    public $links;
    public $mainLinksCount=0;
    public $pc=0;
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $image;
    public $sellingPrice;
    public $maximumRetailPrice;
    public $productURL;
    public $flag=0;

    function __construct()
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
        $this->curl($this->baseUrl);
    }

    public function curl($url)
    {       
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        $this->result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
    }

    public function getProductFeedJason($res)
    {
        $i=0;

        $productFeeds = json_decode($res, TRUE);

        $this->links = $productFeeds['apiGroups']['affiliate']['apiListings'];

        foreach($this->links as $keys=>$value)
        {
            $this->links[$i] = $value['availableVariants']['v0.1.0']['get'];
            //echo $this->links[$i];
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }

    public function getProducts($res, $str)
    {   
        $products = null;
        $products = json_decode($res, TRUE);

        $outerPart = $products['productInfoList'];
        $nextUrl = $products['nextUrl'];
        //echo $nextUrl.'<br />';

        foreach($outerPart as $data)
        {
            $t = $data['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['title'];
            similar_text($str, $t, $percent);
            if($percent>70)
            {
                $this->id[$this->pc] = $data['productBaseInfo']['productIdentifier']              ['productId'];
                //echo $this->id[$this->pc].'<br />';

                $this->title[$this->pc] = $data['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['title'];
                //echo $this->title[$this->pc].'<br />';

                $this->image[$this->pc] = $data['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['imageUrls']['400x400'];
                //echo $this->image[$this->pc].'<br />';

                $this->sellingPrice[$this->pc] = $data['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['sellingPrice']['amount'];
                //echo $this->sellingPrice[$this->pc].'<br />';

                $this->maximumRetailPrice[$this->pc] = $data['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['maximumRetailPrice']['amount'];
                //echo $this->maximumRetailPrice[$this->pc].'<br />';

                $this->productUrl[$this->pc] = $data['productBaseInfo']['productAttributes']['productUrl'];
                //echo $this->productUrl[$this->pc].'<br />';

                $this->pc = $this->pc+1;

                if($this->pc >=10)
                {
                    $this->flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if($nextUrl && $this->flag==0)
        {
            $this->curl($nextUrl);
            $this->getProducts($this->result, $str);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what is the bottleneck ? - 40min is awfully long - if its download time (o_0) : how about caching those 50 resources

Comment: I did save all the data in a MySQL table whose size went up to 15MB. Is a table of that size feasible for searching? @birdspider

Comment: I personally regard a 15mb sql table as 'tiny'